# Any changes made to Laravel blade templates will not show in my local environment - tried cache clearing

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Using:

`MAMP 5.7`

`Laravel 5.4`

I have my company's main website cloned into my local environment. I have gotten everything up and running and all the views render correctly. My problem comes when I attempt to alter any of the blade templates. Any `HTML` I add to it or remove from it is completely ignored when I run it on the Apache server.

What I have tried:

-Clearing the Apache and Laravel caches (`php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`)

-Opening up r/w file permissions on every folder

I am stumped. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Update**

When going directly to the blade template file path (`/views/path/to/template/template.blade.php`), the content I added will render. It just seems to not render when I run it though the `localhost/path` route.

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache as well

Comment: @TheLastStark Tried this too. Unfortunately nothing new is rendering still.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands

```
php artisan dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

I hope it helps